# symlink on bash on windows : apache tries to open a .htaccess that doesn't exist

Tags: apache, symlink, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i try to work on a php project that uses symlinks (it was developped on linux).
i'm on windows, i use **bash on windows** aka **bash on ubuntu on windows** aka **windows subsystem for linux** as a development server.

when apache tries to reach a file within the symlinks it fails.
e.g. when i try to open /var/www/website/symlink/index.html it returns a 403 :

```
[core:error] [pid 742] AH00554: Access to file /var/www/website/symlink/.htaccess denied by server: not a regular file
```

i don't know why but it seems apache tries to open a .htaccess file that does not exist, and of course fails at it.
(the symlink points out of the scope of the virtualhost root)

everything is 777.
i can successfully access /var/www/website/symlink/index.html from the command line.
i can successfully access the index.html file when i remove the symlink and copy its target directory instead.
i've tried to delete symlinks and recreate them, it doesn't change anything.
i've tried to create /var/www/website/symlink/.htaccess but it doesn't change anything.

does it sound like a bug or a bad apache configuration or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was related to this bug :  https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/650

i got everything to work by removing symlinks and recreate them without trailing slash.

it seems that in a symlink with a trailing slash every directories and every files exist (just try to `cd dsfkjhgfkdshjajklhdaf` e.g.)
this explains that apache was finding a non existent .htaccess file and was desperately trying to read it.

i wonder when this bug will get fixed though...

Comment: It's already fixed on Insider Builds. Fix will be included on Win10 Creators Update. (release on March 2017)